# Signals has a different ground from power ground in multiplexer IC

Tags: grounding, multiplexer

I am looking at this [multiplexer](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/CD4051BE/67305) CD4051BE. Below is the pinout of the chip. I power the chip with 12V and feed PWM signals into the channel pins of the chip. However, the PWM signals have their own GND, say PGND (while power's ground is GND).

So, my question is when I get my PWM signal back at COM pin, I will probe the signal at COM using the AGND. Will there be any issue giving the fact that my signal has a different ground from the power ground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can be sure, that minimum and maximum voltage of the PWM signal are not below VEE or above VDD of the 4051, there is no problem.

But to guarantee that in practice, you need a limited DC voltage difference between PWM GND and VSS of the 4051. This is also important at power up of the circuit.

If PWM GND is floating relative to VSS, the PWM signal can reach the supply limits of the 4051 and dangerous current can flow through the internal protection diodes.

The resistance of the switches in the multiplexer is higher if the signal, that passes, is close to VEE or VDD. If analog signals are routed, they should not use the full voltage range between VEE and VDD.

In your setup I assume, that you feed VDD with +12 V and connect VSS and VEE to GND. The PWM signal contains only positive pulses relative to PWM GND. In this context the PWM GND must be >= 0 V relative to VSS.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me a better sense of what I need to consider.